# Html5, textbox with the disable attribute

Tags: html

just a quick question, in html5 a textbox with the disable attribute. Something like this.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled">
```

How can I change the icon in the curson, from a block/not allow sign to a pointer sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may Try css to this

```
input:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that: <span style="cursor:pointer">textbox</span>, but doesnt work.

Comment: Try in the input element itself and not to its container.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style in your css, and try

```
input:disabled:hover{
    cursor : pointer;
}
```